# How to loop database model in laravel

Tags: laravel

I specified the connection and the table name in my Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class object_mapping extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $table = 'object_mapping';
    public $connection = 'mysql1';
}
```

Added the model to my controller file
`use App\Models\object_mapping;`

And now I need to loop through it extracting `userFK != 0`

What should my loop look like?

Comment: Looking at your code and based on your reply to me, I highly recommend you review the links I supplied previously.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment you made:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$objectMappings = DB::table('object_mapping')->get();

foreach ($objectMappings as $objectMapping)
{
    dump($objectMapping->id);
}
```

Also I would suggest naming your model according the the convention. In your case your Model Class name would be : `ObjectMapping`